# Why is ActiveTagMatcher is ignoring some of the values I'm passing to it?

Tags: python, python-behave

I've been successfully using `ActiveTagMatcher` to tag some tests that should be run under some conditions, but for some reason `ActiveTagMatcher` is ignoring some of the values I set. I've boiled it down to this example:

`features/test.feature`:

```
Feature: foo

# This does not work!
@only.with_variable_one=True
Scenario: variable one must be True
  Then something

# This works fine.
@only.with_variable_two=foo
Scenario: variable two must be foo
  Then something

# Try to see if shortening it to something that does not use the `=` works.
# It does not work either.  
@only.with_variable_one
Scenario: variable two must be foo
  Then something
```

`features/environment.py`:

```
import os

from behave.tag_matcher import ActiveTagMatcher

def before_all(context):
    condition = context.config.userdata.get("condition", None) is not None
    values = {
        "variable_one": condition,
        "variable_two": "foo"
    }
    context.active_tag_matcher = ActiveTagMatcher(values)

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    if context.active_tag_matcher.should_exclude_with(scenario.effective_tags):
        scenario.skip(reason="Disabled by an active tag")
        return
```

I have a `features/steps/something.py` which contains just enough to avoid complaints about the step being undefined:

```
@then(u"something")
def step_impl(context):
    pass
```

Running `behave` should only skip the 1st scenario only if I do not invoke it with `-D condition`, **but it always skips the 1st scenario!** Conversely, it is **never skipping the last scenario!**

I'm using Behave 1.2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick Answer

Make sure all your values in your `values` dictionary are strings:

```
values = {
    "variable_one": str(condition),
    "variable_two": "foo"
}
```

And `@only.with_variable_one` for your last scenario *cannot* work. You must have an equal-sign and a value for the tag to work with `ActiveTagMatcher`.

#### Longer Explanation

Let's start with the easy bit. The tag `@only.with_variable_one` is simply not recognized by the `ActiveTagMacher` at all. There exist other tags that don't need to use an operator to indicate that they should be active if the condition they correspond to is true. For instance, you write `@wip` when you want to use Behave's builtin work-in-progress feature, not `@wip=True`. However, the `ActiveTagMacher` requires that there be an equal sign in the tag that you use, otherwise it does not recognize it. So `@only.with_variable_one` is flat out ignored.

The reason `@only.with_variable_one=True` is not working for you is because `ActiveTagMatcher`'s parsing of the tag will result in reading `True` as the string `"True"` whereas in your `values` dictionary you pass a the boolean value `True`. `ActiveTagMacher` uses `operator.eq` to check for equality. So the test is performs is equivalent to `"True" == True`, which is false in Python. So the equality check always fails and thus `ActiveTagMacher` always excludes your scenario. You can fix this by converting your boolean to a string:

```
values = {
    "variable_one": str(condition),
    "variable_two": "foo"
}
```

In fact, every single value in your `values` dictionary must be a string. For instance, if you have a number in there, you must also convert it to a string. Otherwise, tests that are performed against that number won't ever be true.